# maximum spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I wonder how to prove that given a Minimum Spanning Tree of a graph, the other spanning tree with the least common edge with Minimum Spanning Tree is always Maximum Spanning tree.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by a "minimum spanning tree?"

Comment: A minimum spanning tree of a weighted graph is a spanning tree of that graph with minimum total possible weights. You can find it here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that “the other spanning tree with the least common edge with Minimum Spanning Tree” means that if $T’$ is a spanning tree with minimum number of  common edges with a given minimum spanning tree $T$. Then the claim may fail and $T’$ can be non-maximal. For instance, let $G=K_5$ be a complete graph with $n=5$ vertices. Let weight of a fixed edge $e$ of $G$ is $2$ and weights of all other edges of $G$ are $1$. Let $T$ be a spanning tree of $G$. Then $T$ is a minimum spanning tree iff $e$ is not an edge of $T$ and $T$ is a maximum spanning tree iff $e$ is an edge of $T$. To refute the claim it remains to note that there are two edge-disjoint spanning trees of $G$ not containing $e$.